# need to find all file shared within group and directly to user neo4j Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to find all the files directly shared with the user or via a group created by someone else.

I tried the following query it is giving results, however, if no file has been shared directly with the user or via group then I see three nodes with no relation.

it might be possible the same file is shared directly to the user and with the group and the user is part of that group too. In this case, I need a file which is directly shared with the user not the group one.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqVyI.png)

I have also attached the dump for our database

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6cc18b36e9f682aeeed8244d8b36719520200102081814/57ac4525bca19391b7e737547f93bc3d20200102081814/c9d04e

```
match (u:user) where u.ohrid = "120"
match (f:file)
optional match (u)-[mg:MEMBER_OF_GROUP|CREATED_GROUP]->(g:group)<-[fswg:FILE_SHARED_WITH_GROUP]-(f)
optional match (f)-[fsw:FILE_SHARED_WITH]->(u)
return u, mg,fswg, g, fsw, f
```

Need Help ...

Comment: Could you please share your data model

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6cc18b36e9f682aeeed8244d8b36719520200102081814/57ac4525bca19391b7e737547f93bc3d20200102081814/c9d04e

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work for you:

```
MATCH (u:user) WHERE u.ohrid = "120"
OPTIONAL MATCH p1 = (f1:file)-[:FILE_SHARED_WITH]->(u)
WITH u, COLLECT(DISTINCT f1) AS f1s, COLLECT(p1) AS p1s
OPTIONAL MATCH p2 = (u)-[:MEMBER_OF_GROUP|CREATED_GROUP]->(:group)<-[:FILE_SHARED_WITH_GROUP]-(f2:file)
WHERE NOT f2 IN f1s
RETURN u, f1s, p1s, COLLECT(DISTINCT f2) AS f2s, COLLECT(p2) AS p2s
```

This query first finds and collects all files (`f1s`) directly shared with the `user`, along with the paths (`p1s`) to those files. Then it collects all the files (`f2s`) shared with groups associated with the user (ignoring files already in `f1s`), along with the paths (`p2s`) to those files, and returns the `user` and the 4 collections.

Answer (score 0):

replace optional match with where cluse
and or them

```
 match (u:user) where u.ohrid = "120"
 match (f:file)
 where (u)-[mg:MEMBER_OF_GROUP|CREATED_GROUP]->(:group)<-[:FILE_SHARED_WITH_GROUP]-(f)
 optional match (f)-[:FILE_SHARED_WITH]->(u)
 return u, f
```

Comment: Variable `mg` not defined (line 3, column 13 (offset: 69))
" where (u)-[mg:MEMBER_OF_GROUP|CREATED_GROUP]->(:group)<-[:FILE_SHARED_WITH_GROUP]-(f)"